# How to make a discrete ListPlot3D look like a Histogram3D?

Tags: plotting, style, plot-themes

I want to plot a list of 3D points and make it look like this:

[image: Discrete 3D Plot]

where each value is represented by the height of a rectangular parallelepiped (with square top and bottom face).

As a simple example I'm using:

```
T=Flatten[Table[{x,y,Sin[x y]},{x,0,\[Pi]/2,\[Pi]/4},{y,0,\[Pi]/2,\[Pi]/4}],1];
ListPlot3D[T,InterpolationOrder->0,PlotTheme-> "Monochrome" ,Filling-> Bottom,BoundaryStyle->Directive[Black,Thick]]
```

And got this:

[image: Example]

which is much more complex than I wished. The plot dynamically changes color as I rotate it, the filling can be made 'solid' using `FillingStyle` and `Opacity` but it creates an homogeneous filling instead of having the vertical lines and simple white color on the sides.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: something like `tT = Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/16}, {y, 
    0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/16}];
BarChart3D[tT[[All, All, -1]], ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
   BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   "Canvas" -> False, "FaceGrids" -> None][[1]] // 
 Graphics3D[#, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/GoldenRatio}] &`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks for your answer! It's really close to what I'm looking for. I wanted a simple white plot with black edges. I tried messing around with ColorFunction and ColorFunctionScaling but with no luck. Could you comment a little bit your code so I can understand what you did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
T = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x y]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi /16}, {y, 0, Pi, Pi /16}], 1];
```

### ListPlot3D

```
ListPlot3D[T, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[Glow@White]], 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[Glow@White]], 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

### Histogram3D

```
heights = Partition[T[[All, -1]], Sqrt[Length@T]];

Histogram3D[{{0, 0}}, {Range[0, Pi, Pi/16]}, (heights &), 
  ChartStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[Glow @ White]], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

### DiscretePlot3D

```
iF = Interpolation[T];
DiscretePlot3D[iF[x, y], {x, 0, Pi, Pi/16}, {y, 0, Pi, Pi/16}, 
 ExtentSize -> Full, BoxRatios -> 1, FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[{Opacity[1], Glow[White]}]]]
```

[image]

### BarChart3D

```
BarChart3D[heights, ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> {0, 0}, 
 "Canvas" -> False, "FaceGrids" -> None, Boxed -> True, 
 ChartStyle -> White, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Saw your answer after I commented you comment. Let me take a look.

Comment: Thanks! It is very close to what I was looking for. I did think of using discrete plot after interpolating the list of points but it felt like cheating. It's really sad that ListPlot3D doesn't have an easy way out for this.

Comment: Pierre, Thank you for the accept. Added `ListPlot3D`.